# How do you add two df to a plot map?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, jupyter

I want to combine `df1.plot()` and `df0.plot()` onto one plot graph. Currently, when running both, it will give me two plot maps, and I'm out of my expertise on how to join both of them.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [25, 10]
df = df.sort_values('datetime', ascending=True)
df1.plot()
df0.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot images]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
df1.plot()
df0.plot()
```

The following code will help:

```
plt.plot(df1["X"], df1["Y"])
plt.plot(df0["X"], df0["Y"])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either entirely switch over to Matplotlib code as [Mohit Mehlawat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73890084/4458369) suggested, or you can keep using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) by setting an `ax` variable and place both plots on it like so:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Value':[5,4,3,2,1]})

# Relevant code
ax = df1.plot()
df2.plot(ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]